# MailChimp leid duplicates

Tags: mailchimp

The MailChimp documentation mentions about `leid` being unique inside a list.

Is the `leid`, which is unique inside a list, also unique if compared to `leid` in another list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MailChimp `leid` is simply a database primary key for the join table between a List and an Email. So within an account, an `leid` identifies both an email address and a particular list.

So the short answer to your question is 'yes', `leid` won't be duplicated within one account.

That said, MailChimp API v3.0 (currently in beta) has removed `leid` from use, choosing to use the MD5 of the email address instead, so if you're writing new code you should probably avoid relying on `leid` for anything critical.